# How to schedule python script to exit at given time

Tags: python, exit, schedule

I need to schedule a python script which can exit and kill it self at a given time. For scheduling, I am using python `schedule` and below is the code:

```
import schedule
from threading import Thread
import time
import sys


def exit_data():
    print("Exiting")
    sys.exit()

def exit_data_thread():
    schedule.every().day.at('13:20').do(exit_data)
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)


def main():
    Thread(target=exit_data_thread).start()

    while True:
        time.sleep(1)

main()
```

Function `exit_data()` runs at given time and it prints `Exiting` but do not exit. It only prints `Exiting` and then it keeps running. I have also used  `quit` instead of `sys.exit()`. Please help. Thanks

Comment: How can you tell that the script is not exiting? Can you provide a bit more information on what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to send signal to yourself :p

```
import schedule
from threading import Thread
import time
import sys
import os
import signal


def exit_data():
    print("Exiting")

    # sys.exit()
    os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGTERM)

def exit_data_thread():
    schedule.every(3).seconds.do(exit_data)
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)


def main():
    Thread(target=exit_data_thread).start()

    while True:
        time.sleep(1)

main()
```

Answer (score 2):

To close the entire program within a thread, you can use `os._exit()`. Calling `sys.exit()` will only exit the thread, not the entire program.