# How to pause or stop python program between certain hours (not based on elapsed time!)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading, scheduling, exit

I am trying to find a way of leaving my python program running continuously, but ensuring that the main script is only 'active' during nightime hours (e.g. between 21:30 and 04:30 for example)

Background: My program records motion activated video & activates a floodlight.

The main program segment is below:

...I am currently running this each evening and then killing in the morning with Ctrl-C..!

```
try:

signal.signal(signal.SIGHUP,SigHandler) # proper exit for SIGHUP (terminal hangups)

while GPIO.input(PIR_PIN)==1: # Loop until PIR output is stabilised at 0
    pass

GPIO.add_event_detect(PIR_PIN, GPIO.RISING, callback=MotionDetected)

signal.pause() #pauses main program forever & waits for PIR Rising Edge unless interrupted

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("")

finally:
    GPIO.output(16, GPIO.LOW) #floodlight off
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Is there a way of checking time periodically in a parallel thread perhaps, and suspending program if time betweeen certain hours?

Might the solution posted below work for my program perhaps if I add the thread statement before my try statement?...

[How to schedule python script to exit at given time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53424532/how-to-schedule-python-script-to-exit-at-given-time)

Comment: Normally it should be handled on OS level.

Comment: time module with time.sleep() is your needed tool, here a full tuto https://www.journaldev.com/15797/python-time-sleep

Comment: @Cyber-Tech that won't work because the main thread pauses and waits for an event. It can't simultaneously check how much time has elapsed while waiting for input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, create a cron job (I believe you're on Linux because of the GPIO calls), to start the script every night at 21:30.

`30 21 * * * python /path/to/python/script`

Then, create a second cron job at 4:30 to kill any existing processes that are running your program.

`30 4 * * * pkill -f /path/to/python/script  # Will need to be edited to the actual process name that runs.`

[Killing a process by matching name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6381266/7586861)

Comment: Thanks @jarcobi889. Yes Linux OS. I'll explore the cron approach further, however the problem / challenge here is getting the program to exit gracefully with the kill command. (I.e. turning off the floodlight, finish recording a video if already in progress, and cleanup the GPIO states before exit) Any ideas on this approach?

Comment: You would use the [signal](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/signal.html) module to detect the kill interrupt and use that to set your final states like finishing recording video and turning off the floodlight before exiting.

Comment: Thanks - will further explore that module and post final code here if / when successful :-)

Answer (score 1):

Python Pause https://github.com/jgillick/python-pause/ supports pause until a certain datetime.

Also Java Threads 2nd edition has an example code of a job scheduler; maybe you can use it as a blue print.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I've paused this project for many months but hope to get back to it in future and will try this out.